# How do I share data between kernel C programs and user level C programs?

Tags: c, linux-kernel, kernel

I am using Ubuntu 9.04 with kernel 2.8.32. I created a simple system call that counts the number of [clone](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clone_%28Linux_system_call%29) and [execve](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exec_%28operating_system%29#Prototypes) calls. When the user/shell calls this system call, I would like it to pass back to the user these two values. As of now I am using:

```
#include <linux/sched.h>
#include <linux/asmlinkage>

/* These two variables are extern longs which are defined in sched.h and initialized in process_32.c */

total_execve;
total_clones;

long mycall* (int i){
    int array[2];
    array[0] = total_execve;
    array[1] = total_clones;
    return array;
}
```

I am not able to compile this as I get an undefined reference.

Regarding returning the array: Will my new call be able to access the array, won't the array be located in kernel memory?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answering your last question first:  the array is indeed in "kernel" memory, but it's *stack allocated* which means it wilL "go away" when the mycall() function exits.  Your function may appear to work, but may fail in cases where the memory gets re-used quickly.

To return multiple values, the common pattern is for the caller to pass in pointers to user-space memory, and have the kernel routine to fill them in.  For example, you could pass in two pointers for your two values, or define a single struct that contains the values you need and gets filled in by the kernel routine.

Comment: Shouldn't you be using the copy_to_user and copy_from_user helper functions?

Answer (score 5):

Don't return pointers into the stack. Have the caller pass pointers into the function. Also, your function declaration syntax is incorrect. Here's what you want to do:

```
void mycall (int *execve, int *clones)
{
    *execve = total_execve;
    *clones = total_clones;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot return an array in this way. You need to declare static keyword to return a local array function. You could do something like this:

```
int *mycall (int i) {
    static int array[2];
    array[0] = total_execve;
    array[1] = total_clones;
    return array;        
}
```